# Is it recommended to use Observer pattern with a ResultSet as event source?

Tags: java, design-patterns, iterator, observer-pattern, resultset

I have a JDBC query that will generate a huge [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) which cannot be stored in memory. To each result some following complex logic should be applied. I don't want to put everything inside the loop over that resultset. Is it recommanded to use obserber pattern by making the class with JDBC query as [`Observable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html)? Or should I make that class an [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever the design, you'll have to loop over the ResultSet. Don't overengineer what you just need is something like this:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    SomeObject o = extractDataFromResultSet(rs);
    process(o);
}
```

The process method is free to do what it wants : do the job, invoke collaborating objects, etc.

Comment: Well, this is the easist way, but isn't it against SRP?

Comment: If process consists in calling someObjectProcessor.process(o), no. Just pass the someObjectProcessor object to your method, or to the constructor.

Comment: @chance: That depends on what you're going to do with `SomeObject`. You could also move `process(SomeObject)` method to another object.